# multi Input with shared weights in Keras

Tags: keras

Im trying to build network like this:
[the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfewf.png)

and my question is how to implement the begining with the **shared weights**, 
because it contains FC+BN+ReLu (3-layers), and I have multi inputs vectors( M(~25) vectors with length=F).

I tried with functional API modle in keras, and I had some diffculty with this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `TimeDistributed` over each layer.

For example:

```
model = Sequential()    
model.add(TimeDistributed(MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet',include_top=False), input_shape=(n_sequence, *dim, n_channels)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))  
model.add(Dense(n_output, activation='softmax'))
```

Code has been taken from https://github.com/peachman05/action-recognition-tutorial/blob/master/model_ML.py